# How can other users be updated when a comment is posted, other than the author in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

We have a wordpress setup, with a closed user group (ie one cannot create a login for himself). Whenever I write a blog & comments are posted to it, I get updated over mail. But, how to make sure to update other users also.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a Wordpress subscription plugin.  The most well known plugin for this is called Subscribe2.  I think it works for registered users.  If not, browse Wordpress's Extend page for a similar one.  I suppose solving your problem like this doesn't make it much of a programming problem, but why re-write code?

[Subscribe2](http://subscribe2.wordpress.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The one I have used is [Subscribe to Comments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe-to-comments/) and it has worked great. Others include [Subscribe to Comments Now!](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe-to-comments-now/) and the one Chet mentioned, [Subscribe2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe2/screenshots/). Subscribe2 seems to have the best admin interface out of the three, I think I might try that one.